# How to use Angular service to provide third party APIs like leaflet or google maps?

Tags: angular, google-maps, leaflet

I am new to Angular. I want to know whether I can use a service to provide a third party API, like leaflet or google maps, to a component?

I have written a service in which I have HTTP request to leaflet API URL, which contains javascript functions. I am returning the observable from the service to my map component.

Here's the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LeafletService {
  private Lurl = "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js";
  httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Content-type': 'application/json'});

  urlText: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getL():Observable<any>{

    return this.http.get(this.Lurl);
  };

}
```

Here's the map component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {LeafletService} from '../../services/leaflet.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css'],
  providers: [LeafletService]
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  L: any;

  constructor(private llService: LeafletService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getL();     
  }

  getL(): void{

    this.llService.getL().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.L = data;
        return this.L;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  } 
}
```

Based on the assumption that all HTTP GET responses are JSON strings, I was expecting to receive a JSON string and then I wanted to parse it to get the javascript function. However, soon after I use subscribe,  angular is giving an HTTP response error because it is trying to JSON parse the response.

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js", ok: false, …}
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: "/* @preserve↵ * Leaflet 1.5.1+build.2e3e0ff, a JS …function(){return window.L=zn,this},window.L=t});"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

Is my understanding about using services to provide an API wrong or is my implementation wrong? Please help.

Comment: I don't check, but take a look to https://codehandbook.org/use-leaflet-in-angular/

Comment: this link might be helpful: https://medium.com/@hassam.dev/integrating-google-maps-in-angular-d3d478c5f1c6?source=your_stories_page---------------------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the use of services is to request APIs to provide their data to components in your app. You tried to HTTP GET a javascript file though.

As such, the error is `Unexpected token / in JSON`, because it's not JSON, it's JS.

To load an external JS file, you can follow this Angular guide about how to use [published libraries](https://angular.io/guide/using-libraries).

The npm dependencies for leafletjs are:  `leaflet` and `@types/leaflet`.